# Interesting Insect, possibly a beetle (Northern Indiana)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I happened across an interesting looking insect, that I've never seen before.  In Northern Indiana, late spring around 5 PM CST.  I tried a reverse image search, with no luck.  It is approximately 3/4 inch long.

Any ideas?

[image: Beetle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a carrion beetle. Family Silphidae, in the genus *Necrophila*
https://www.insectidentification.org/insect-description.asp?identification=American-Carrion-Beetle

Comment: Ugh.  After reading the linked page, I'm sorry I asked.  ;)